# Automatic Login with AD domain user on Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04

Tags: 22.04, active-directory, auto-login

Does anyone know how to configure Ubuntu LTS 20.04 or 22.04 (Using default Gnome desktop) to perform autologin using a domain user account?

The client has been joined to the domain and it is possible to manually sign in to it using a domain account. However, autologin does not work.

The GUI does not contain the option to autologin when using domain account and changing the value in custom.conf results in the client halting at bootup.

Any help is much appreciated.

//Mikael